# Radial Tree layout algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, graph-visualization

I have implemented a tree data structure in which every node holds (recursivly) a list of pointers to it's children.

I am trying to calculate the (x,y) coordinates for visualizing the tree. 
I went through this article:

http://gbook.org/projects/RadialTreeGraph.pdf

Cut I can't figure out how to gest past the first level, i.e This is what I have written so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GetDepth()+1; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        GetNodesInDepth(i).at(0)->SetXRadial(MIDDLE(m_nWidth));
        GetNodesInDepth(i).at(0)->SetYRadial(MIDDLE(m_nHeight));
        continue;
    }

    double dNodesInDepth = GetNodesInDepth(i).size();
    double dAngleSpace = 2 * PI / dNodesInDepth;

    for (int j = 0; j < dNodesInDepth; j++)
    {
        Node * pCurrentNode = GetNodesInDepth(i).at(j);

        pCurrentNode->SetXRadial((SPACING * i) * qCos(j * dAngleSpace) + MIDDLE(m_nWidth));
        pCurrentNode->SetYRadial((SPACING * i) * qSin(j * dAngleSpace) + MIDDLE(m_nHeight));
        pCurrentNode->m_dAngle = dAngleSpace * j;

        if (pCurrentNode->IsParent())
        {
         //..(I'm stuck here)..//  
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to calculate the limits, bisectors etc.
this is what my drawer did so far:

[image: This image shows that two edges of the graph intersect]

which is obviously not what i'm looking for since the second (0 based) level.

I have access to every info that I need in order to obtain what I'm looking for.

Comment: So (to clarify) in your graph, the only one misplaced is the 30 node?

Comment: The link you gave sort of has the code for what you are trying to do. It's pretty messy but has the calculation of the limits and bisectors at different levels. Are you having problems understanding their code?

Comment: I have tried it. it didn't work...

Comment: You are using the systems hungarian notation. Many people think it's an antipattern: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/style-and-techniques#hungarian

Comment: Are `MIDDLE` and `SPACING` macros?

Comment: Your interface and data structure choice seams strange to me. I'd made a `Node` class that is responsible for storing, deleting and iterating through it's childs. But I don't know your requirements can conditions. May be it all makes prefect sense in your situation.

Comment: What does `ezqt` stand for?

Comment: What's with you? I didn't ask for a code review. My question was clear enough so you wouldn't need to discuss anything that is irrelevant for the problem.

Comment: my notations and variables names are irrelevent.

Comment: I'm sorry. You are right. I'm going to redirect my `code_review_stream` to a temporary file.

Comment: I personally don' think the algorithm in the paper is very good.  You'd generally get nicer results by spacing the leaves evenly around the outside and working backward toward the center, with each parent centered (radially) on its children.  As a special case, you'd have to handle the case where the tangent constraint is broken (e.g. a single parent has an enormous number of children). With this scheme, the root would not have its children at equal angles.  The graph's density would be more even.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably by now you figured it out yourself. If not, here

```
double dNodesInDepth = GetNodesInDepth(i).size();
double dAngleSpace = 2 * PI / dNodesInDepth;
```

you're setting the angle space to PI (180 degreees) at your second level, as there are only two nodes at that level, `dNodesInDepth = 2`. That's why after drawing the node 20, the node 30 is 180 degrees away. That method would be fine for very dense trees because that angle will be small. But in your case you want to keep the angle as close as possible to the angle of the parent. So I suggest you get the angle of the parent for nodes at level 2 and higher, and spread the children so they have an angle space of `sibilingAngle = min(dAngleSpace, PI/10)`. So the first child will have the exact angle of the parent, and the remaining children are `sibilingAngle` away from one another. You get the idea and probably come with a better method. I'm using `min` in case you have got too many nodes at that level you want to squeeze the nodes closer to each other.

The article you've linked to, uses a solution that is illustrated in `Figure 2 – Tangent and bisector limits for directories`. I don't like that method much because if you determine the absolute angle of the children rather than relative to the parent you can have a simpler/cleaner solution that does exactly what that method tries to do with so many operations.

**Update:**

The following code produces this image:

[image]

I think you can easily figure out how to center the child nodes and etc.

```
#include <cairo/cairo.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    Node() {
        parent = 0;
        angle = 0;
        angleRange = 2*M_PI;
        depth = 0;
    }
    void addChildren(int n) {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            Node* c = new Node;
            c->parent = this;
            c->depth = depth+1;
            children.push_back(c);
        }
    }
    vector<Node*> children;
    float angle;
    float angleRange;
    Node* parent;
    int depth;
    int x, y;
};

void rotate(float x, float y, float angle, float& nx, float& ny) {
    nx = x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle);
    ny = x * sin(angle) + y * cos(angle);
}
void draw(Node* root, cairo_t *cr) {
    if (root->parent == 0) {
        root->x = root->y = 300;
        cairo_arc(cr, root->x, root->y, 3, 0, 2 * M_PI);
    }

    int n = root->children.size();
    for (int i=0; i<root->children.size(); i++) {
        root->children[i]->angle = root->angle + root->angleRange/n * i;
        root->children[i]->angleRange = root->angleRange/n;

        float x, y;
        rotate(40 * root->children[i]->depth, 0, root->children[i]->angle, x, y);
        root->children[i]->x = 300+x;
        root->children[i]->y = 300+y;

        cairo_move_to(cr, root->x, root->y);
        cairo_line_to(cr, root->children[i]->x, root->children[i]->y);
        cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
        cairo_stroke(cr);

        cairo_arc(cr, 300+x, 300+y, 3, 0, 2 * M_PI);
        cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 1, 1);
        cairo_stroke_preserve(cr);
        cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
        cairo_fill(cr);

        draw(root->children[i], cr);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    Node root;
    root.addChildren(4);
    root.children[0]->addChildren(3);
    root.children[0]->children[0]->addChildren(2);
    root.children[1]->addChildren(5);
    root.children[2]->addChildren(5);
    root.children[2]->children[1]->addChildren(2);
    root.children[2]->children[1]->children[1]->addChildren(2);

    cairo_surface_t *surface;
    cairo_t *cr;

    surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 600, 600);
    cr = cairo_create(surface);

    cairo_rectangle(cr, 0.0, 0.0, 600, 600);
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 1, 1);
    cairo_fill(cr);

    cairo_set_line_width(cr, 2);

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        cairo_arc(cr, 300, 300, 40*i, 0, 2 * M_PI);
        cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, .5, .5, .5);
        cairo_stroke(cr);
    }

    draw(&root, cr);

    cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "image.png");

    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);

    return 0;
}
```

**Update 2:**
Just to make it easier for you, here is how to center the nodes:

[image]

```
for (int i=0; i<root->children.size(); i++) {
    float centerAdjust = 0;
    if (root->parent != 0) {
        centerAdjust = (-root->angleRange + root->angleRange / n) / 2;
    }
    root->children[i]->angle = root->angle + root->angleRange/n * i + centerAdjust;
    root->children[i]->angleRange = root->angleRange/n;
```

Showing a more populated tree:
[image]

Comment: I have tried what you suggested. I'm nt sure how to define the angle for each level though. what I got split every anglespace in every level equally on the whole level circle

Comment: Thanks for the ellaborated solution. I tried writing the code without the cairo part (I only need the x, y coords) but it put all of them on the same X axis

Comment: Then you have made a mistake, best is to share your code, I will try to have a look

Comment: Thanks! in the original code search for `for (int i=0; i<root->children.size(); i++) {` then from that line to `root->children[i]->angleRange = root->angleRange/n;` should be replace with that updated block of code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of the algorithm from the article that should work (note: I didn't compile it since I don't have other parts of your program):

```
void Tree::CalculateAngles()
{
    // IsEmpty() returns true if the tree is empty, false otherwise
    if (!IsEmpty())
    {
        Node* pRoot = GetNodesInDepth(0).at(0);
        pRoot->SetAngle(0);
        // Relative to the current angle
        pRoot->SetTangentLimit(PI);
        // Absolute limit
        pRoot->SetLowerBisector(-PI);
        pRoot->SetHigherBisector(PI);
    }
    for (int depth = 1; depth < GetDepth() + 1; depth++)
    {
        double dDepth = (double)depth;
        // The last non-leaf node in of the current depth (i.e. node with children)
        Node* pPreviousNonleafNode = NULL;
        // The first non-leaf node
        Node* pFirstNonleafNode = NULL;
        // The parent of the previous node
        Node* pPreviousParent = NULL;
        int indexInCurrentParent = 0;
        double dTangentLimt = acos( dDepth / (dDepth + 1.0) );
        for (int i = 0; i < GetNodesInDepth(depth).size(); i++)
        {
            Node* pCurrentNode = GetNodesInDepth(depth).at(i);
            Node* pParent = pCurrentNode->GetParent();
            if (pParent != pPreviousParent)
            {
                pPreviousParent = pParent;
                indexInCurrentParent = 0;
            }
            // (GetMaxChildAngle() - GetMinChildAngle()) / GetChildCount()
            double angleSpace = pParent->GetAngleSpace();
            pCurrentNode->SetAngle(angleSpace * (indexInCurrentParent + 0.5));
            pCurrentNode->SetTangentLimit(dTangentLimt);
            if (pCurrentNode->IsParent())
            {
                if (!pPreviousNonleafNode)
                {
                    pFirstNonleafNode = pCurrentNode;
                }
                else
                {
                    double dBisector = (pPreviousNonleafNode->GetAngle() + pCurrentNode->GetAngle()) / 2.0;
                    pPreviousNonleafNode->SetHigherBisector(dBisector);
                    pCurrentNode->SetLowerBisector(dBisector);
                }
                pPreviousNonleafNode = pCurrentNode;
            }
            indexInCurrentParent++;
        }
        if (pPreviousNonleafNode && pFirstNonleafNode)
        {
            if (pPreviousNonleafNode == pFirstNonleafNode)
            {
                double dAngle = pFirstNonleafNode->GetAngle();
                pFirstNonleafNode->SetLowerBisector(dAngle - PI);
                pFirstNonleafNode->SetHigherBisector(dAngle + PI);
            }
            else
            {
                double dBisector = PI + (pPreviousNonleafNode->GetAngle() + pFirstNonleafNode->GetAngle()) / 2.0;
                pFirstNonleafNode->SetLowerBisector(dBisector);
                pPreviousNonleafNode->SetHigherBisector(dBisector);
            }
        }
    }
}

void Tree::CalculatePositions()
{
    for (int depth = 0; depth < GetDepth() + 1; depth++)
    {
        double redius = SPACING * depth;
        for (int i = 0; i < GetNodesInDepth(depth).size(); i++)
        {
            Node* pCurrentNode = GetNodesInDepth(depth).at(i);
            double angle = pCurrentNode->GetAngle();
            pCurrentNode->SetXRadial(redius * qCos(angle) + MIDDLE(m_nWidth));
            pCurrentNode->SetYRadial(redius * qSin(angle) + MIDDLE(m_nHeight));
        }
    }
}

void Tree::CalculateLayout ()
{
    CalculateAngles();
    CalculatePositions();
}

double Node::GetAngleSpace()
{
    return (GetMaxChildAngle() - GetMinChildAngle()) / GetChildCount();
}
```

Note: I tried to mimic your code style so you won't have to refactor it to match other parts of your program.

P.S. If you spot any bugs, please notify me in the comments - I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. I will try this tomorrow and will keep you posted for any issues.

Comment: actually there is a problem with the line: double angleSpace = pParent->GetAngleSpace(); it looks odd to me that this member field (angleSpace) is not modified anywhere but only accessed.
Also - the lines: double mid_x = MIDDLE(m_nWidth) etc.,
m_nWidth is the layout of the screen, and it's constant (defind at tree declartion). what are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: Who said you that getters should have their corresponding fields and setters? This function is supposed to calculate the angle space based on the angle range and the number of child nodes (see comments).  About mid_x: it doesn't really improve anything, but it doesn't make it worse either.

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer I guess I used `mid_x` because it would make your code (from the question) smaller, but now I look as my code and see that a direct call of MIDDLE simplifies my code (changed it).

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer BTW now I see even better solution: make the `Node` calculate x and y on it's own (yes, again getters w/o setters).

Comment: The implementation of GetAngleSpace is GetMaxChildAngle() - GetMinChildAngle()) / GetChildCount?

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer Yes. I edited my answer to indicate it better. Note that `GetMinChildAngle()` and `GetMaxChildAngle()` are getters w/o setters too (I'll add it to the answer when I have time).