# Why Radial tree layout drawing algorithm is making crossed edges?

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree, graph-visualization, radial

I am implementing radial layout drawing algorithm, according to the publication of mr.Andy Pavlo [link](http://scholarworks.rit.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1355&context=theses) *[page 18]*

The problem is, that my result contains crossed edges. Which is something that is unacceptable. I found some solution, similiar problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328245/radial-tree-layout-algorithm) but I was not able to implement them into this algorithm (I would have to change the whole approach to the solution). In addition, the algorithm by Mr. Andy Pavlo should be able to solve this problem. When we look at the result of its algorithm, there are no crossed edges here. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? Thank you in advance.

**Mr.Pavlo pseudo code of algorithm**
[image]

**My  implementation of algorithm**

```
        public void RadialPositions(Tree<string> rootedTree, Node<string> vertex, double alfa, double beta,
        List<RadialPoint<string>> outputGraph)
    {
        //check if vertex is root of rootedTree
        if (vertex.IsRoot)
        {
            vertex.Point.X = 0;
            vertex.Point.Y = 0;
            outputGraph.Add(new RadialPoint<string>
            {
                Node = vertex,
                Point = new Point
                {
                    X = 0,
                    Y = 0
                },
                ParentPoint = null
            });

        }
        //Depth of vertex starting from 0
        int depthOfVertex = vertex.Depth;
        double theta = alfa;
        double radius = Constants.CircleRadius + (Constants.Delta * depthOfVertex);

        //Leaves number in the subtree rooted at v
        int leavesNumber = BFS.BreatFirstSearch(vertex);
        foreach (var child in vertex.Children)
        {
            //Leaves number in the subtree rooted at child
            int lambda = BFS.BreatFirstSearch(child);
            double mi = theta + ((double)lambda / leavesNumber * (beta - alfa));

            double x = radius * Math.Cos((theta + mi) / 2.0);
            double y = radius * Math.Sin((theta + mi) / 2.0);

            //setting x and y
            child.Point.X = x;
            child.Point.Y = y;

            outputGraph.Add(new RadialPoint<string>
            {
                Node = child,
                Point = new Point
                {
                    X = x,
                    Y = y,
                    Radius = radius
                },
                ParentPoint = vertex.Point

            });

            if (child.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                child.Point.Y = y;
                child.Point.X = x;
                RadialPositions(rootedTree, child, theta, mi, outputGraph);
            }
            theta = mi;
        }

    }
```

**BFS algorithm for getting leaves**

```
    public static int BreatFirstSearch<T>(Node<T> root)
    {
        var visited = new List<Node<T>>();
        var queue = new Queue<Node<T>>();
        int leaves = 0;

        visited.Add(root);
        queue.Enqueue(root);

        while (queue.Count != 0)
        {
            var current = queue.Dequeue();
            if (current.Children.Count == 0)
                leaves++;
            foreach (var node in current.Children)
            {
                if (!visited.Contains(node))
                {
                    visited.Add(node);
                    queue.Enqueue(node);
                }
            }
        }

        return leaves;
    }
```

**Initial call**

```
        var outputPoints = new List<RadialPoint<string>>();
        alg.RadialPositions(tree, tree.Root,0, 360, outputPoints);
```

**mr.Pavlo result**
[image]

**My result on simple sample**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.Cos` and `Sin` expect the input angle to be in *radians*, not degrees. In your initial method call, your upper angle limit (`beta`) should be `2 * Math.PI`, not `360`. This will ensure that all the angles you calculate will be in radians and not degrees.

Comment: Million thanks, works perfectly. This has not occurred to me at all.