# Why aren't my child nodes centered above the parentnodes in radial tree?

Tags: python, math, tree, nodes

Using the algorithm from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328245/radial-tree-layout-algorithm) I was able to create a radial tree with points that represent each node. The problem is though that child nodes are not centered on the parent and are offset somewhat. I saw there was a similar problem in the above answer but even after implementing it doesn't seem to be keeping the children centered. Am I translating wrong? I am not too familiar with all the ins and outs of C++ but I've gotten this far.

I have a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394111/how-to-plot-images-as-a-radial-tree-only-using-math) that I asked, which is related to this, but is not the same question. I want to update the answer once this is resolved so others can know what to do.

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree
import math

#Start setting positions from node, starting from root tree object.
def RadialPositions(node):

    # Set root to x=0, y=0, if not already set.
    if node.is_root:
        node.positions = (0, 0)

    #Number of children in current node
    nChildren = len(node.children)

    #Rotate child to above parent
    def rotate_node(x, y, nangle):
        nx = x * math.cos(nangle) - y * math.sin(nangle)
        ny = x * math.sin(nangle) + y * math.cos(nangle)
        return nx, ny

    # For every child, set angle
    for idx, child_node in enumerate(node.children, start=1):

        #Adjust from parent degree
        centerAdjust = 0

        # If node has a parent, adujust to center
        if node.parent:
            centerAdjust = (-node.angleRange + node.angleRange / nChildren) / 2

        ##Set child node angle and max angle range
        child_node.nodeAngle = node.nodeAngle + node.angleRange / nChildren * idx + centerAdjust
        child_node.angleRange = node.angleRange / nChildren

        #Set positions
        x = rotate_node(40 * child_node.depth, 0, child_node.nodeAngle)[0]
        y = rotate_node(40 * child_node.depth, 0, child_node.nodeAngle)[1]


        child_node.positions = (3 * x, 3 * y)

        # For each child of child, iterate same process
        RadialPositions(child_node)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue by setting the enumerate to 0 instead of 1. This was causing the nodes to be offset by one instead of the natural parent.